# can you show stats from only 1 static ga:id with google analytics api?

Tags: google-analytics-api

What I want to do: I want to display my GA stats on my site to a select Group of people who also have access to the sites Google analytics. Simple as that.

I have gotten the API to work, but in all the examples the user has to select a site from their own list of ga accounts, which means that they can view data from their other sites on my site....and that just gets weird and confusing.

I have tried to enter a static id code, but it still selects the first GA account for that user.

Comment: Use a service account instead of Oauth2.  Oauth2 will let them see there own data. Using a service account you can set it up to give them access to your data.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into that

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling the API? The [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) takes an [ids](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#ids) parameter which you can hard code into your API requests.